# What am doing wrong in here?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, addeventlistener, parseint

Input value always gets into if condition first even am parsing it to parseInt() and when page refreshed with a number it gets into else condition, like its not registering the inputValue at first place, also if i add a submit event rather an click one event doesnt fires up.

```
HTML
<div class="addHere"></div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:"/>
    <button class="btn">+</button>
  </div>

javaScript
    // this line was modified
    const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
    
    const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");
    
    document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", addInputs);
    
    fucntion addInputs() {
    if(isNaN(inputValue)) {
    alert("Wrong input");
    } else {
    for ( let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
      const form = document.createElement("form");
          form.method = "post";
          form.action = "#";
    
          const input1 = document.createElement("input");
          input1.type = "text";
          input1.maxLength = "12";
          input1.className = "factor";
          input1.required = true;
    
          const input2 = document.createElement("input");
          input2.type = "text";
          input2.maxLength = "1";
          input2.className = "priority";
          input2.required = true;
    
          const br = document.createElement("br");
    
          form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
          form.appendChild(input1);
          form.appendChild(input2);
          form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    
          div.appendChild(form);
        }
    
        const sub = document.createElement("button");
        sub.type = "submit";
        sub.value = "Submit";
        sub.className = "subButton";
        sub.textContent = "Submit";
    
        div.appendChild(sub);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recording the value of the input on page load, so at first it is empty.

Move this line

```
    const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
```

to be the first line of your function that runs after clicking your button.

```
    function addInputs() {
    const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
```

Also it is probably best to use ID's for those elements and select them by their ID's rather than a class. ID's are unique so there can only be one of them on the page.

I also corrected typos in those lines, missing " and misspelled function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
```

Is being executed once, so every time you click on *+* button it won't read value of the  tag. You have to move this statement inside you click handler, like this:

```js
function addInputs() {
  // this should be here, so every time you click on + button, actuall values is being read
  const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
  if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
    alert("Wrong input");
  } else {
    for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
      const form = document.createElement("form");
  ...
```

Also here:

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");
```

I could not find *div* with such class in your HTML, so you have to add it like this, I think:

```html
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
    <button class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="addHere"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an " in the first line in javascript code.

```
const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
```

Comment: It's unlikely this is the actual problem given OPs description of the problem.

Comment: @Ali Fakoor sorry but that was typing mistake, i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", addInputs);

function addInputs() {

  const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);

  for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
    const form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = "#";

    const input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.type = "text";
    input1.maxLength = "12";
    input1.className = "factor";
    input1.required = true;

    const input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.maxLength = "1";
    input2.className = "priority";
    input2.required = true;

    const br = document.createElement("br");

    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    form.appendChild(input1);
    form.appendChild(input2);
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

    div.appendChild(form);
  }

  const sub = document.createElement("button");
  sub.type = "submit";
  sub.value = "Submit";
  sub.className = "subButton";
  sub.textContent = "Submit";

  div.appendChild(sub);

}
```

```html
<div class="addHere"></div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9"  class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unlikely this is the actual problem given OPs description of the problem.

Comment: Your submit button seems to be somewhere not inside the form.

Comment: @hashBender that was typo, now edited.if i move that submit button inside form it will appear after every input field and i dont want that.

Comment: What's your desired output is not clear to me? But you can refactor your code. If you want just a number as input then you can change type="number" and for length to be one, add min="0" max="9". Doing that you don't have to parse the number to int.
I'm editing the answer once again with running code snippet to see if that's what you want.